# RunTime Error 9 VBA- Copying a row of data from one worksheet to another within the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time writing a program in Visual Basic. I am trying to 
write a program that takes a Worksheet of raw data (Sheet 17), sorts through this 
data appropriately, and copies over good rows of data to another sheet in the workbook.

My code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim First_Row As Integer
Dim Last_Row As Integer
Dim i, j, k, m As Integer

Dim Bad_Cell As Boolean

Dim Orig_Data As Worksheet
Dim New_Data As Worksheet

Dim Orig_Range As Range
Dim New_Range As Range

Set Orig_Data = Worksheets("17")
Set New_Data = Worksheets("18")


         First_Row = Application.InputBox _
         (Prompt:="Please enter the row where data filtering will start", _
                Title:="Filter", Type:=1)



    If First_Row = 0 Then

        Exit Sub

    Else

          Last_Row = Application.InputBox _
         (Prompt:="Please enter the row where data filtering will end", _
          Title:="Filter", Type:=1)


          If Last_Row = 0 Then

             Exit Sub

          End If

    End If

i = First_Row
m = 2

Do

   j = 2
   k = 1

Do

     Bad_Cell = WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(i, j))

        If Bad_Cell = False Or Cells(i, j) = 0 Then

            Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) + 1 / 24

            j = 2

            k = k + 1

         Else

            j = j + 1

        End If

Loop While j <= 18 And k < 15

Set Orig_Range = Workbooks("Calorimeterics").Orig_Data.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 18))
Set New_Range = Workbooks("Calorimeterics").New_Data.Range(Cells(m, 1), Cells(m, 18))


If k < 15 Then

   Orig_Range.Copy
   New_Data.Activate
   New_Range.Select

   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
   Operation:=xlNone, _
   SkipBlanks:=False, _
   Transpose:=False

  i = i + 1
  m = m + 1

Else

   i = i + 1

End If

Loop While i <= Last_Row

End Sub
```

My problems occur at the point of trying to copy and paste a row from worksheet 17 to worksheet 18.
I am getting Runtime Error 9 Subscript Out of Range'. I have looked at other responses to similar types of questions, but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use fully qualified name for `Cells` object (specify sheet, which cells belongs to):

change

```
Set Orig_Range = Workbooks("Calorimeterics").Orig_Data.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 18))
Set New_Range = Workbooks("Calorimeterics").New_Data.Range(Cells(m, 1), Cells(m, 18))
```

to

```
Set Orig_Range = Orig_Data.Range(Orig_Data.Cells(i, 1), Orig_Data.Cells(i, 18))
Set New_Range = New_Data.Range(New_Data.Cells(m, 1), New_Data.Cells(m, 18))
```

One more thing with your code:

When you are using `Workbooks("Calorimeterics").Orig_Data`, Excel tries to find *property* of `Workbooks("Calorimeterics")` with name `Orig_Data` but, `Workbooks("Calorimeterics")` doesn't support property with name `Orig_Data` or `New_Data` (and that's triggers an error).

If you'd like `Orig_Data` and `New_Data` to be from "Calorimeterics" workbook, change also

```
Set Orig_Data = Worksheets("17")
Set New_Data = Worksheets("18")
```

to

```
Set Orig_Data = Workbooks("Calorimeterics").Worksheets("17")
Set New_Data = Workbooks("Calorimeterics").Worksheets("18")
```

but make sure, that "Calorimeterics" workbook is opened at the time code is running.

Comment: Thank you so much! After first looking at your response, I overlooked that you had deleted out Workbooks("Calorimetrics"). May I ask why that should be left out, apart from the fact that it now works.

Comment: yup! You're right! When you are using `Workbooks("Calorimeterics").Orig_Data` Excel tries to find _property_ of `Workbooks("Calorimeterics")` with name `Orig_Data` but, `Workbooks("Calorimeterics")` doesn't support property with name `Orig_Data` or `New_Data` (and that's triggers an error). So, if you'd like to specify workbook for your sheets, see my updated answer:)